# Fewer than 4 huffman tables in a JPEG file?

Tags: jpeg, decode

So I've been attempting to write my own JPEG decoder (In Lua for the ROBLOX platform if that's of any use) and in every guide I find online, it always uses an example where the image has 4 distinct Huffman tables. 1 for DC Luminance, 1 for AC Luminance, 1 for DC Chrominance, and 1 for AC Chrominance. When this is the case, my decoder works fine and everything is happy and nice. However when trying to decode some random jpeg images off the internet, I find that a lot of them have fewer than 4 Huffman tables, and in these cases my decoder fails miserably. I've tried researching for if there are some standard Huffman tables I should use as defaults for when the other tables aren't present, or if I should instead use a duplicate of one of the tables as a replacement for the missing ones, but I have come up empty handed. Any help on the subject would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The Huffman tables are never misssing. I guess your problem is that you parse the DHT marker segment incompletely (DHT can hold multiple Huffman tables).

Comment: Alternatively, can you share one of those problematic files?

Comment: @DaBler Sure, here's one https://onlinejpgtools.com/images/examples-onlinejpgtools/mouse.jpg

Comment: This one has one DHT segment with four Huffman tables.

Comment: More precisely: ```DHT: Tc = 0 (DC table) Th = 0 (HT identifier); Tc = 0 (DC table) Th = 1 (HT identifier); Tc = 1 (AC table) Th = 0 (HT identifier); Tc = 1 (AC table) Th = 1 (HT identifier)```

Comment: Wait, so there can be only one DHT marker and multiple tables per marker? That explains a lot, thank you. I was so confused for the longest time, I had no clue why my parser was showing only one DHT marker when usually there were four in all the tutorials I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so thank you to DaBler in explaining this to me in the comments on my original question, it was extremely helpful.

Apparently you can have multiple Huffman Tables under one DHT marker, which I did not know. I'll see if I can get it working and thank you for the help!